# Expectation problem with geometric random variable?

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value

If I have a stream of integers from 0 to 9(each with equal probability and repetition is allowed) that are spewed out until I get the first instance of 4-5 next to each other in this order, how do I find the expected value of the number of integers that will be printed?

I set up a random variable, $X$, that is the number of integers printed, and an indicator random variable, $X_i$, that is 1 if the $I^{th}$ number does not complete the first instance of 4-5, and 0 otherwise. I think that the probability that $X_i$ = 1 is calculated as $1 - (1/10)^2$, so would the expected value of $X$ just be $1/p$?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your computation.  It would appear that the expected value of the $i^{th}$ term would be a function of $i$, since you would need to ensure that the game wasn't over before the $i^{th}$ move.  Anyway, here is another approach:

There are three states here...$\emptyset,4,\{4,5\}$ according to how much of the $4,5$ block occurs at the end of the running string.  Letting $E_S$ deonte the expected number it will take to finish assuming you are starting in state $S$, we note that the answer we want is $E=E_{\emptyset}$.  Of course $E_{\{4,5\}}=0$.

Noting that $\emptyset$ can only transition to $\emptyset$ (probability .9) or $4$ (probability .1) we compute  $$E_{\emptyset}=\frac 9{10}\times (E_{\emptyset}+1)+\frac 1{10}\times (E_4+1)\implies E_{\emptyset}=E_4+10$$

Similarly  $$E_4=\frac 1{10}\times 1+\frac 1{10}(E_4+1)+\frac 8{10}\times (E_{\emptyset}+1)\implies 9E_4=8E_{\emptyset}+10$$

This system is easy to solve and we get $$\boxed {E_{\emptyset}=100}\quad \&\quad \boxed {E_4=90}$$